# In Ms Word TOC (table of content) and Hyprelinks are not showing proper way on my system

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I am facing a problem in my Ms. Word 2007. The problem is TOC (table of content) and Hyperlinks are not showing proper way on my system, where as while opening same document on other system is showing content properly.

This problem I started facing recently, earlier I don't have this problem.

I can come out of this problem by re-installing the Ms. Office software. But I don't want to do that, rather I want to know cause of this and what setting changes I have to do to solve this

**Sample view**
[image]

Any suggestion or help is appreciated

Comment: This is not a programming question and belongs on a different site, such as Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggle the field code view off by pressing `Alt+F9` (or right-click into the field and choose *Toggle Fields Codes*).